# Emploi de OK en français

Tags: usage, anglicismes

L'emploi de OK est-il permis en français ? Est-il considéré comme un anglicisme ou non ? L'utilise-t-on comme en anglais ? Est-ce que sa prononciation à l'anglaise est standard ou non ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On trouve cette locution adverbiale dans le TLFi, mais sous la forme « O.K. » ; elle a pour synonymes reconnus (pour l'instant) les termes suivants : **(c'est) d'accord, bien, bon, oui, parfaitement**. La prononciation doit être « [oke] »; on peut aussi l'écrire « **okay** ». Cela permet de conclure que la locution fait partie du français et qu'elle est entièrement francisée en sa forme pleine. De toute façon je crois qu'on ne pourrais pas parler vraiment d'anglicisme mais seulement d'américanisme; c'est une locution qui a son origine dans le parler américain. Comme l'on considère que la forme pleine n'est que la transcription des sons des lettres « o » et « k » et que la forme initiale consiste des lettres seulement, la prononciation ne peut pas être considérée comme étant francisée, mais elle est standard puisque reconnue par le TLFi. On trouve déjà cette locution en français en 1870.

Son utilisation est loin d'être aussi variée qu'en anglais et en américain dans le parler français contemporain; cependant, fondamentalement elle est utilisée comme en américain. Les synonymes montrent cela.

Il faut considérer qu'en américain elle est devenu **un adjectif, un verbe, un nom et une exclamation** dont les sens sont apparentés.

Comment: lié à cette question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49978/traduire-lantonyme-de-ok