# Traduire l'antonyme de OK

Tags: traduction, informatique, anglicismes

En traduisant un programme informatique, on s'est posé la question de la traduction d'`OK` et son antonyme. Pas très clair même en anglais (d'où [cette autre question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586525/what-is-the-ok-antonym)).

Est-ce que `KO` en français, c'est OK ou KO ?

Comment: Que signifie la question *Est-ce que le KO pour le Français, c'est OK ou bien KO ?* ??

Comment: Et en traduisant à partir de quelle langue ?

Comment: Il faut donner le code ou contexte. Dire OK comme ça - dans le vide -  ne veut rien dire, informatique ou pas. D'autant plus, que le mot OK en anglais n'a pas "d'antonyme". Pour information, KO veut dire knock out.

Comment: Il est dommage que sur le site anglais, ils aient fermé cette question, injustement, à mon avis.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est un jeu de mot utilisant les mots de la question je pense. Je vois ça comme : "*Est-ce que "incorrect" c'est correct ou incorrect ?*".

Comment: @Oreste Elle est off-topic sur ELU (*linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*). Elle aurait peut-être eu plus de chances sur ELL. On ne sait toujours pas dans quelle langue OK et KO sont utilisés dans le programme en question.

Answer (score 2):

Dans un contexte professionnel en informatique, j'ai rencontré fréquemment `KO` et `NOK`. C'étaient les codes de retour qu'on avait sur certains jobs, et entre développeurs c'était parfaitement compris.

Je pense que si ton programme en anglais utilise les codes retours `OK` et `KO` tu peux les garder en français. Ça fait partie des innombrables anglicismes du milieu auxquels on ne fait même plus attention.

Answer (score 1):

'OK' or rather 'O.K.' is used in French. See the answer in the question [Emploi de OK en français](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32662/emploi-de-ok-en-fran%C3%A7ais). But in this programming context, I would suggest something like

`x < y : correct`

and

`x > y : erreur`

Comment: pour l'utilisation de OK, l'auteur du programme utilise "OK", cela c'est pas un soucis, j'ai des doutes sur l'emploi de son *antonyme* dans diverses langues, effectivement, "erreur" pourrait être une bonne suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

La paire `OK` - `KO` est un usage français et aussi [apparemment italien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201477/why-jmeter-failures-marks-as-ko), mais `KO` est généralement incompris par les anglophones dans ce contexte.

Le mieux serait d'utiliser les deux signes anglais suivants qui ont tendance à s'internationaliser :

```
x < y : ✔  

x > y : ✘
```

L'idéal est aussi de mettre la coche en vert et la croix en rouge, certains pays considérant les deux marques comme équivalentes et signifiant non/faux/incorrect.

En restant dans le domaine des symboles, on pourrait aussi utiliser les suivants (pouce levé ou baissé):

```
x < y :   

x > y :
```

Sinon,

```
x < y : Correct  

x > y : Incorrect
```